# Point godaddy domain to dedicated server (Windows Server 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, godaddy

That is it. So i have a godaddy domain and a server running Windows Server 2003 + WAMP with a public static IP (accesible via internet). So, the only thing i want to know is how to point my godaddy domain to my server.

I already searched for hours but looks like i am writing the wrong words or something...

For any experienced server manager this must be a really stupid question but i truly can't figure out exactly how; i have been messing with DNS and CNAMES and A records with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make sure that the DNS is currently pointed to GoDaddy's nameservers (which it is by default if you registered the domain through them). After that, you need a single A record that states that the requests for your domain are pointed to your static IP. It will not be immediate, it takes time for the caching to occur, could be as long as 48 hours until it works.

Comment: It says its not immediate, but I've yet to see it not go into effect within a couple of seconds and I have 4 GoDaddy servers.

Comment: If you don't have to change your domain to point to GoDaddy's nameservers, it should be nearly instant. It's changing the nameservers that takes a long time. Changing the data in the nameservers should be less than a minute.

Comment: Thanks MaQleod, it worked! BTW just for curiosity: is there other way to do this and does it have any advanges or disadventages?